# Flutter: adjust height of PageView/Horizontal ListView based on current child

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a carousel with items of variable heights. When using PageView or ListView with horizontal scrolling, I need to give it a constant height, like this:

```
class CarouselVariableHightState extends State<CarouselVariableHight> {
  double height = 200;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Carousel')),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('My Carousel'),
          Container(
            height: height,
            child: PageView(
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildCarouselItem(),
                _buildCarouselItem(),
                _buildCarouselItem(),
                _buildCarouselItem(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Text('end of List')
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCarouselItem() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: Random().nextInt(200).toDouble(),
          child: Text('Text with random length')
        )
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

But my items contain text and I don't know the length of it. I don't wan't to limit the height of a CarouselItem because it might cut off the text. How could I have something like a PageView, that adjust its own size based on the currently shown item?

I thought a solution could be to get the height of the CarouselItem and then set it to the height of the PageView. However I couldn't figure out a way to get the height my current Carousel item.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Johnykutty nope, I opened this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29749

Comment: I came here from that issue, there also no response :(

Comment: yeah unfortunately I don't think there is a solution right now

Answer (score 82):

Below you can find an example of a PageView that adapts its height to currently displayed child. With animation:

[image: ExpandablePageView example]

The idea is:

1. We wrap each child of PageView with a custom widget that can report widget size after each frame. Here I called it `SizeReportingWidget`.
2. Each height is saved in a list, called `_heights` on an index that corresponds to the child's index.
3. Attach a PageController that will let you determine the currently displayed page's index. Here we save it to a field called `_currentPage`
4. Wrap `PageView` in a `SizedBox` and give it the height of the currently displayed child. I've added a convenient getter called `_currentHeight` to retrieve the height.
5. (Optional) Wrap the `SizedBox` in `TweenAnimationBuilder`, so that the height changes are smooth and animated rather than clanky jumps.

### **`ExpandablePageView`**

```
class ExpandablePageView extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Widget> children;

  const ExpandablePageView({
    Key? key,
    required this.children,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExpandablePageView> createState() => _ExpandablePageViewState();
}

class _ExpandablePageViewState extends State<ExpandablePageView>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late PageController _pageController;
  late List<double> _heights;
  int _currentPage = 0;

  double get _currentHeight => _heights[_currentPage];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _heights = widget.children.map((e) => 0.0).toList();
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController()
      ..addListener(() {
        final newPage = _pageController.page?.round() ?? 0;
        if (_currentPage != newPage) {
          setState(() => _currentPage = newPage);
        }
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
      curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      tween: Tween<double>(begin: _heights[0], end: _currentHeight),
      builder: (context, value, child) => SizedBox(height: value, child: child),
      child: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        children: _sizeReportingChildren
            .asMap() //
            .map((index, child) => MapEntry(index, child))
            .values
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> get _sizeReportingChildren => widget.children
      .asMap() //
      .map(
        (index, child) => MapEntry(
          index,
          OverflowBox(
            //needed, so that parent won't impose its constraints on the children, thus skewing the measurement results.
            minHeight: 0,
            maxHeight: double.infinity,
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: SizeReportingWidget(
              onSizeChange: (size) =>
                  setState(() => _heights[index] = size.height),
              child: Align(child: child),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
      .values
      .toList();
}
```

### `SizeReportingWidget`

```
class SizeReportingWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final ValueChanged<Size> onSizeChange;

  const SizeReportingWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.onSizeChange,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SizeReportingWidget> createState() => _SizeReportingWidgetState();
}

class _SizeReportingWidgetState extends State<SizeReportingWidget> {
  Size? _oldSize;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _notifySize());
    return widget.child;
  }

  void _notifySize() {
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }
    final size = context.size;
    if (_oldSize != size && size != null) {
      _oldSize = size;
      widget.onSizeChange(size);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this should be accepted answer.. you saved me bro

Comment: I guess this is his published package: https://pub.dev/packages/expandable_page_view

Comment: If you want to have animated heights in it you can cover the ExpandablePageView with ValueListenableBuilder. After that create and pass a ValueNotifier from parent to animated widget and adjust ValueNotifier inside that Animation. Finally you'll have crappy animation on page changes. Because there are two animation at the same time (Your widget's animation and ExpandablePageView's). To prevent that, use this duration property in ExpandablePageView's TweenAnimationBuilder `_currentPage == 0 && _pageController.page == 0 ? const Duration(milliseconds: 0) : const Duration(milliseconds: 300)`

Comment: How about we find out what page has maximum height and make that the height of the "PageView", that way it will not change in height and bounce all the time we slide through the items

Comment: @KristiJorgji that would require you to layout all pages beforehand which might cause a big overhead for performance and kills the purpose of having lazily loaded items in PageView. But it should be also posssible

Comment: I seem to get an infinite height exception when I use the expandable_page_view package. Anyone else? I don't see it as a bug in GitHub, so I think it is just me...

Answer (score 12):

There are 2 possible solutions: right one and hacky one.

1. The Right solution:
   Because PageView is trying to get all posible height, we can't use it inside of any widget, that dont' have height. So if we don't have height we need to use another widget, for example StackWidget and re-create PageView behavior: swipes, animations etc. It won't be a big library, if you want to make just simple things, less than 200-300 lines I guess.
2. The hacky solution is to check the height of all elements before you build the PageView widget. You cannot change the height of the elements when PageView is build. So if you need to have for example a server request make it before you render the carusel.

To get the height, it easier to use IndexedStack, becouse it has the height of the highest element, but show only the first one (by default).

- use keys to get the height of IndexedStack
- use setState to save it.
- use obtained height as the height of PageView.

[image]

```
class CarouselVariableHight extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CarouselVariableHightState createState() => CarouselVariableHightState();
}

final widgetHeights = <double>[
  Random().nextInt(300).toDouble(),
  Random().nextInt(300).toDouble(),
  Random().nextInt(300).toDouble(),
  Random().nextInt(300).toDouble(),
];

class CarouselVariableHightState extends State<CarouselVariableHight> {
  double height;
  GlobalKey stackKey = GlobalKey();
  bool widgetHasHeigh;

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);
    super.initState();
  }

  _afterLayout(_) {
    final RenderBox renderBoxRed = stackKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final sizeRed = renderBoxRed.size;
    setState(() {
      height = sizeRed.height;
    });
  }

  final caruselItems = widgetHeights
      .map((height) => Column(children: [
            Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                height: Random().nextInt(300).toDouble(),
                child: Text('Text with random length'))
          ]))
      .toList();

  _buildStack() {
    Widget firstElement;
    if (height == null) {
      firstElement = Container();
    } else {
      firstElement = Container(
        height: height,
        child: PageView(
          children: caruselItems,
        ),
      );
    }

    return IndexedStack(
      key: stackKey,
      children: <Widget>[
        firstElement,
        ...caruselItems,
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Carousel')),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('My Carousel'),
          _buildStack(),
          Text('end of List'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I follow this and get error
The method 'findRenderObject' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: findRenderObject()
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @QuyenAnhNguyen did you set a key?

Comment: Yes, I did. I don't have this error anymore but height is not change :(

Comment: it's hard to say what is problem without seeing your code

Comment: Stack will not have a dynamic height so no it it will not work as expected, only children will have the right height

Comment: `renderBoxRed` has error. What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

To use PageView inside a ListView you can use [ExpandablePageView](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable_page_view) Package from pub.dev.

Here is an expample:

```
ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          ExpandablePageView(
            children: [
              GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  childAspectRatio: 0.9,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 18,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 18,
                ),
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  childAspectRatio: 0.9,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 18,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 18,
                ),
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Copy the below code and use it as usual like a normal pageViewer.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpandablePageView extends StatefulWidget {
  final int itemCount;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, int) itemBuilder;
  final PageController? controller;
  final ValueChanged<int>? onPageChanged;
  final bool reverse;

  const ExpandablePageView({
    required this.itemCount,
    required this.itemBuilder,
    this.controller,
    this.onPageChanged,
    this.reverse = false,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExpandablePageView> createState() => _ExpandablePageViewState();
}

class _ExpandablePageViewState extends State<ExpandablePageView> {
  late PageController _pageController;
  late List<double> _heights;
  int _currentPage = 0;

  double get _currentHeight => _heights[_currentPage];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _heights = List.filled(widget.itemCount, 0, growable: true);
    _pageController = widget.controller ?? PageController();
    _pageController.addListener(_updatePage);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.removeListener(_updatePage);
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
      curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic,
      tween: Tween<double>(begin: _heights.first, end: _currentHeight),
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      builder: (context, value, child) => SizedBox(height: value, child: child),
      child: PageView.builder(
        controller: _pageController,
        itemCount: widget.itemCount,
        itemBuilder: _itemBuilder,
        onPageChanged: widget.onPageChanged,
        reverse: widget.reverse,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
    final item = widget.itemBuilder(context, index);
    return OverflowBox(
      minHeight: 0,
      maxHeight: double.infinity,
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: SizeReportingWidget(
        onSizeChange: (size) =>
            setState(() => _heights[index] = size.height ?? 0),
        child: item,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _updatePage() {
    final newPage = _pageController.page?.round() ?? 0;
    if (_currentPage != newPage) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPage = newPage;
      });
    }
  }
}

class SizeReportingWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final ValueChanged<Size> onSizeChange;

  const SizeReportingWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.onSizeChange,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SizeReportingWidget> createState() => _SizeReportingWidgetState();
}

class _SizeReportingWidgetState extends State<SizeReportingWidget> {
  Size? _oldSize;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _notifySize());
    return widget.child;
  }

  void _notifySize() {
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }
    final size = context.size;
    if (_oldSize != size && size != null) {
      _oldSize = size;
      widget.onSizeChange(size);
    }
  }
}
```

You can use this with as same as like the PageView

Answer (score 0):

[expandable_page_view](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable_page_view) use the expandable_page_view pub for dynamic heights based on child.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much more straightforward solution if you don't need to have content below the PageView.

The PageView itself doesn't need to be the visible portion; only its children do. I've made the PageView take up the remainder of the page height (and its children are vertically scrollable if they take up more height than the page). The content of each of the PageView children is the only bit you see. My children are Cards with no height set. Each card is the height of its children and changes its height when its children do (in my case, it gets taller when error messages display).