# container size doesn't change in pageView.builder

Tags: flutter

[image]

this is the result of my code.

I have four images to use in `PageView` widget, and
as some of image's size are different from another picture, I want to fit size of pictures through boxfit. But to do boxfit, the height of picture is so long.

So I restricted `Container` with height property, but no matter how I set the height of the container in makePage widget, (ex, 100, height/8 ...)
height of the container is fixed (green container)

Is this because of viewportFraction? Does anyone know what causes this?

_makePage widget returns each pages(image) for PageView

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dots_indicator/dots_indicator.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(body: DotIndicator()),
    );
  }
}

class DotIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DotIndicatorState createState() => _DotIndicatorState();
}

class _DotIndicatorState extends State<DotIndicator> {
  final List<String> imgEx = [
    'images/1.jpg',
    'images/2.jpg',
    'images/3.jpg',
    'images/4.jpg',
  ];

  //pageView controller
  final _controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8);
  double currentPage = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _showMenuPage(context); 
  }

  Widget _showMenuPage(BuildContext context) {
    final _itemCount = imgEx.length;

    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
      color: Colors.grey[300],
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          PageView.builder(
            controller: _controller,
            itemCount: _itemCount, 
            itemBuilder: (context, itemIndex) {
              return _makePage(context, itemIndex); 
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _makePage(BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /4,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Image.asset(imgEx[itemIndex], ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: so you want to reduce green container? or increase height of image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522980/flutter-adjust-height-of-pageview-horizontal-listview-based-on-current-child

Comment: Oh i wanted to reduce green container

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the image in the `BoxDecoration` of the green `Container`:

```
Widget _makePage(BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /4,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green,
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(imgEx[itemIndex]),
            fit: BoxFit.cover
          )
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

You can put the width and height in the constraints of the container:

```
child: Container(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /4,
            maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
          ),
...
```

Comment: I'm sorry but when I try this solution, the Container size is still same.. (long)

Comment: Did you set the `maxHeight` in `BoxConstraints`? @kw3136

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with just change `height` and `width` as per your need,

```
Widget _showMenuPage(BuildContext context) {
    final _itemCount = imgEx.length;

    return Container(
       height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
       width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
      color: Colors.grey[300],
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          PageView.builder(
            pageSnapping: false,
            controller: _controller,
            itemCount: _itemCount,
            itemBuilder: (context, itemIndex) {
              return _makePage(context, itemIndex);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget _makePage(BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 70),
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.green,
      image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage(imgEx[itemIndex]),fit: BoxFit.cover)),
  ),
);}
```

I still don't get why container size doesn't change with height or BoxConstraints, but i got the result by adding more Padding - EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 70),

[image]