Pageview takes up all the available space
I'm having an issue with a PageView inside a SingleChildScrollView. The PageView is expanding to fill all available vertical space.
Here's the code:
Expanded(
  child: Container(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // Other widgets
        
            child: PageView(
              children: [
                // Page content
              ],
            ),
          
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

I need to keep the PageView height variable based on its content because the content size changes
When I run this code as it is, I see a white screen.
Here's all what I've tried -

I've tried Expanded, Flexible  but those too take up all space
I've tried changing the phyics of PageView to NeverScrollable but still white screen
I've tried fixing the height of Page view (with SizedBox) to MaxFinite but it makes the screen too big. I can scroll forever.

The current result is a blank screen and what I want will look something like this but the problem in this is its scrolling down to infinity (its the third thing I tried).

Here's another way I tried to do it But Slide Animation is missing in this
if (selectedTab['description']!)
                          SizedBox(height: 20),
                        if (selectedTab['description']!)
                          GestureDetector(
                              onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
                                if (details.primaryVelocity! < 0) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    for (var item in selectedTab.keys) {
                                      selectedTab[item] =
                                          item.toLowerCase() ==
                                              "specifications";
                                    }
                                  });
                                }
                              },
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 15, vertical: 15),
                                child: Text(
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                  loremIpsum + loremIpsum,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black54,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    fontFamily: "Main",
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )),
                        if (selectedTab['specifications']!)
                          GestureDetector(
                            onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
                              if (details.primaryVelocity! > 0) {
                                setState(() {
                                  for (var item in selectedTab.keys) {
                                    selectedTab[item] =
                                        item.toLowerCase() == "description";
                                  }
                                });
                              } else if (details.primaryVelocity! < 0) {
                                setState(() {
                                  for (var item in selectedTab.keys) {
                                    selectedTab[item] =
                                        item.toLowerCase() == "review";
                                  }
                                });
                              }
                            },
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 10, vertical: 0),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    Map specifications =
                                        thisProduct['specifications'];
                                    List keys =
                                        specifications.keys.toList();
                                    List values =
                                        specifications.values.toList();
                                    return Column(
                                      children: [
                                        if (index == 0) Divider(),
                                        Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            Container(
                                              color: AppColors.background,
                                              width:
                                                  MediaQuery.sizeOf(context)
                                                          .width *
                                                      0.4,
                                              child: Padding(
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                    .symmetric(
                                                    vertical: 15),
                                                child: Center(
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    textAlign:
                                                        TextAlign.start,
                                                    keys[index],
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                      fontSize: 15,
                                                      fontFamily:
                                                          "BoldMain",
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Container(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              width: (MediaQuery.sizeOf(
                                                              context)
                                                          .width *
                                                      0.6) -
                                                  40,
                                              child: Padding(
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                    .symmetric(
                                                    vertical: 15),
                                                child: Center(
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    textAlign:
                                                        TextAlign.start,
                                                    values[index]
                                                        .toString(),
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                      fontSize: 15,
                                                      fontFamily:
                                                          "BoldMain",
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        Divider(),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  },
                                  itemCount:
                                      thisProduct['specifications'].length,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        if (selectedTab["review"]!)
                          GestureDetector(
                            onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
                              if (details.primaryVelocity! > 0) {
                                setState(() {
                                  for (var item in selectedTab.keys) {
                                    selectedTab[item] =
                                        item.toLowerCase() ==
                                            "specifications";
                                  }
                                });
                              }
                            },
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text("ReVIEW CONTENT"),
                            ),
                          )

Any Help would be Appreciated.
Thank You

I think screenshots would benefit this question, to illustrate 1) what the current result is and 2) what the desired result is.

I have Added the expected result. @TedNyberg

@TedNyberg I have added the result now could you please help me

"I need to keep the PageView height variable based on its content" - you cannot do that, for example if the first page view child has height == 100 and the last has height == 1000 then you would like the page view to have 100 or 1000 pixels in height?

I want it change when i change the page @pskink

so it should smoothly change from 100 to 1000 while you drag the pages?  the user experience would  be terrible imho, and you cannot know the sizes of the pages so it is physically impossible

All i want is it to look like it does in the video but with no space at the end like in the video. I don't prefer using only PageView So i would too appreciate any other option. Since I had already used it, i asked the question in its reference @pskink

Answers here might be related:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/54522980/13179934

@artemniy No sorry, it includes storing the height of each page and changing it But I cant specify the height of the second page as it will have  different number of specifications Thus different heights for each product

If your example works, but doesn't have a slide animation, then try to wrap all pages inside Row, wrapped inside horizontal SingleChildScrollView. Rewrite its physics to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics, then inside onHorizontalDragEnd add scrollController.animateTo() with calculation of Offset based on current page * screen width
Something like this:
 SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  controller: scrollController,
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Page1(),
      Page2(),
      Page3(),
    ],
  ),
)

And then something like this inside onHorizontalDragEnd():
        scrollController.animateTo(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*keys.indexOf('selectedItem'), duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);

